# am new to mysql queries, i want to join these four tables, count the number of students who belong to each school and group them by school name

Tags: mysql, sql

am new to mysql queries, i want to join these four tables i want to count the number of students who belong to each school and group them by school name.

then i want to find the number of  male and female students per school
Note:considering there is actual data in the tables

here is what am trying to do but its not giving actual results

```
 SELECT COUNT(studentid) AS totalStudentsRegistered,
        s.schoolid,s.schoolName
   FROM student s,course c,program p,school s
  WHERE s.cousreid = c.courseid
    AND c.programid= p.programid
    AND p.schoolid= s.schoolid
  GROUP BY s.schoolName

-----------------
   table A (student)
-------------------------------------------------------------
   studentid       | Name     | age    | gender   |courseid
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1              | joe goe  | 23     |male      |1
    2              |sands sou | 20     |female    |2
    3              |marry goe | 23     |male      |1
    4              |jane mand | 20     |female    |2
-------------------------------------------------

table b  (courses)
-------------------------------------------------------------
   courseid        | couseName     | programid
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1              | Math          | 1    
    2              | science       | 2 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 table c (programs)
-------------------------------------------------------------
   programid       | programName        | schoolid
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1              | Degree             | 1    
    2              | Diploma            | 2 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 table c (school)
-------------------------------------
  schoolid         | schoolname     
-------------------------------------
    1              | school of math           
    2              | school of scince        
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such a query

```
SELECT sc.schoolid, sc.schoolName,
       COUNT(st.studentid) AS totalStudentsRegistered,
       SUM(st.gender = 'male') AS totalmalestudent,
       SUM(st.gender = 'female') AS totalfemalestudent 
  FROM student st
  JOIN courses c ON st.courseid = c.courseid
  JOIN programs p ON c.programid = p.programid
  JOIN school sc ON p.schoolid = sc.schoolid
 GROUP BY sc.schoolid, sc.schoolName
```

where

- add all non-aggregated column into the GROUP BY list
- use explicit JOIN syntax among tables instead of comma-seperated old one.
- Here the default JOIN(INNER) is used. That might be replaced by LEFT
  JOIN depending on the data which might be unmatched for the ID
  columns on the JOIN conditions.